# How do I add a field in admin side?

Tags: magento

I have one module installed & in that I need to add one password_guard (password type) field & I also need to check that password (another field) & guard_password should not be the same.

For that in app/code/community/Unirgy/Dropship/Block/Adminhtml/Vendor/Edit/Tab/Form.php

in function _prepareForm() I put the following coding :-

```
$fieldset->addField('password_guard', 'password', array(
        'name'      => 'password_guard',
        'label'     => $hlp->__('Guard Password'),
        'class'     => 'validate-password',
        'note'      => $hlp->__('Leave empty for no change'),
    ));
```

& that field started appearing & also entry goes in DB but now 2 problems....me facing :-
1) How to check? that guard_password & password must not be same (password is already stored in DB)
2) guard_password is stored in DB but it is stored like reset123...means no md5 occurs

So how can I achieve these tasks? In which files the coding needs to be done & how?

Thanks
Kaushal

Answer (score 0):

These validation will be at controller action where you are handeling form submit.
If the password you are talking about is customer password than to match with this will be the code

```
$email = 'dependra@example.com';//It will be the customer email, if customer is logged in than you can get from session also
$toBeCheckPasswd = 'admin123';// your password_guard
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$res = $customer->validatePassword($toBeCheckPasswd);
if($res)
    echo "matches";
else
    echo "do not matche";
```

If it is not cutomer password than

```
$hashedPasswd = "f34c354b4c8ab4fcb88311f1d160a322:fE";//you will get from your table
$res = Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($toBeCheckPasswd, $hashedPasswd);
```

If it was a normal md5 password without salt int it than it just simply

```
try{
    if($md5password==md5($toBeCheckPasswd))
        echo "matches";
    else
        Mage::throwException("Do not match");
}
catch(Excepton $e){
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError( $e->getMessage());
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

md5 encryption is good enough but Magento goes one step further by adding private key(salt) in encryption.
this is how

```
$password = "12345678";
$salt = "at";
$encyPasswod = md5($salt.$pass).":".$salt;
```

and for matching `Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($toBeCheckPasswd, $hashedPasswd);` be used.